# how we can set file pointer new position in terms of lines in c

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing

As i think we have fseek function to set file pointer's new position measured in terms of bytes. How we can move file pointer new position in terms of lines?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: there's no easy way.  A file in C is a bunch of bytes, and there is nothing in particular that makes the bytes '\n' and '\r' special (depending on your system).  If you really care about a general solution, I would recommend building a lookup table for the byte offsets of line endings as you read the file, and then using it to jump around in the file later on.

Answer (score 1):

Cant make pointer directly to the lines . Reads the file

Answer (score 0):

The basic stdio functions operate on bytes only. You will have to read the file byte by byte and count the lines yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My solution was to store the seek positions of some of the lines and doing a forward search from there.

Eg. If you have a million lines, you can store seek positions of every thousandth line.